# testing app that integrates with facebook

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, app-store

I want to test my application's facebook integration.
My application is not released in the appstore yet.
What should I do with bundle ID and appstore ID?
What data to should I write there?
will it work if I provide bundleID and appstore ID of my unreleased but registered app in appstore?

Comment: where do you want to give the bundle ID and appstore ID ?

Comment: Please see my comment to Shai Mishali's answer

Comment: there is no need to give the appstoreId and bundleId... just leave it as blank... Now only I Tested it works fine :)

Comment: Thanks. please reply my question with separate answer. I will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to give the Appstore Id and Bundle Id... just leave it as blank... Now only I Tested it works fine

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what is the question - If the question is "Will i be able to implement Facebook for iOS without the app is registered on the App Store" , the answer is **Yes**.

I usually use and recommend the Facebook iOS SDK which can be found on Github : https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

Facebook also has a really nice guide about the basics of creating the implementation on iOS which can be read here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

Comment: As I know facebook requires to register an application in developers.facebook.com and developers need to provide appstoreID and bundleID of their application. Am i wrong?

Comment: I should work without the AppstoreID, but the budleID you know before you submit.

Comment: I'm pretty sure appstoreID is something you can fill up later, but i'm not 100% definitely sure. About bundleID, thats something you can fill up in the beginning, and change it later for the worst case (i think you can do the same for Appstore ID).

Comment: If i'm trying to provide only application's bundleID without appstoreID i get this error: Error
You have enabled a Native iOS App integration for your app, but have not specified an iPhone App Store ID or iPad App Store ID

Comment: So i guess that answers your question. Did you try writing down a fake Appstore ID for now , and change it later ?